# PHP AJAX XMLHTTPRequest Session always got destroyed without me destroying it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, session-variables

I was able to confirm that my SESSION variable will contain a value but then the next time i run my function it says: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\Reports_db\getvalue.php on line 94

I thought session will retain its values unless session is being destroyed? Why am i not getting the value of my session? Any thoughts?

Here is PHP file (UI)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php include ('includes/header.php');?>

<navigation>
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li role="p_resentation"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li role="p_resentation" class="active"><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
            <li role="p_resentation"><a href="manufacturing.php">Manufacturing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</navigation>
<br />

<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col-sm-8" id="row1-sm8">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="content-heading">
                <form action"" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select name="users" onchange="getvalue(this.value)" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            <option value="">Select a field:</option>
                            <option value="1">Product Name</option>
                            <option value="2">SO #</option>
                            <option value="3">Assembly Name</option>
                            <option value="4">Sales Person</option>
                            <option value="5">Customer Name</option>
                            <option value="6">PO / Remarks</option>
                            <option value="7">SO Status</option>
                            <option value="8">Delivery Status</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                            <input type="text" id="search" onchange="search(this.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="button" id="search_btn" onclick="search(this.value)" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" value="">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    <div class="panel-body" id="output">

                    </div>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="row1-sm4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="login-heading">Filters</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <br/>
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Field</td>
                                <td>Value</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>

<script>
function getvalue(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","_db/getvalue.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
function search(str) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","_db/getvalue.php?q=9",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_btn").click(function(){
        var x = $("#search").val();
        search(x);
    });
    $("#search").keyup  (function(){
        var x = $("#search").val();
        search(x);
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my Codes using the session

```
<html>
<body>
    <table class="table">
<?php
    include('../includes/links/js.php');
    include('../includes/links/css.php');
    include('/connection/connect.php');
    if (isset($_GET['q'])){

        $val = $_GET['q'];
        if ($val < 9) {
            $field = '';
            $field_s = '';
            $group = '';

            if ($val == 1) {
                $field = "(SELECT pp1.name_template FROM product_product pp1 WHERE boml.product_id = pp1.id) as BOML";
                $field_s ="(SELECT pp1.name_template FROM product_product pp1 WHERE boml.product_id = pp1.id)";
                $group = "BOML";
            } elseif ($val == 2) {
                $field == "so.name";
                $group = "SO";
                $field_s = "so.name";
            } elseif ($val == 3) {
                $field = "sol.name as assembly";
                $group = "assembly";
                $field_s = "sol.name";
            } elseif ($val == 4) {
                $field = "split_part(u.login, '@', 1) as sales_person";
                $group = "sales_person";
                $field_s = "split_part(u.login, '@', 1)";
            } elseif ($val == 5) {
                $field = "c.display_name as Customer";
                $group = "Customer";
                $field_s = "c.display_name";
            } elseif ($val == 6) {
                $field = "so.note as PO";
                $group = "PO";
                $field_s = "so.note";
            } elseif ($val == 7) {
                $field = "so.state as Status";
                $group = "Status";
                $field_s = "so.state";
            } elseif ($val == 8) {
                $field = "COALESCE(del.state, 'Waiting Availability') del_status";
                $group = "del_status";
                $field_s = "COALESCE(del.state, 'Waiting Availability')";
            }
            $query = "      FROM sale_order so

                            INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol
                                ON so.id = sol.order_id
                            INNER JOIN res_partner as c
                                ON so.partner_id = c.id
                            LEFT JOIN account_payment_term as ap
                                ON so.payment_term_id = ap.id
                            INNER JOIN product_uom as pu
                                ON sol.product_uom = pu.id
                            LEFT JOIN account_tax_sale_order_line_rel as acs
                                ON sol.id = acs.sale_order_line_id
                            LEFT JOIN account_tax as at
                                ON acs.account_tax_id = at.id
                            INNER JOIN product_template as pt
                                ON sol.product_id = pt.id
                            LEFT JOIN mrp_bom as bom
                                ON pt.id = bom.product_tmpl_id
                            LEFT JOIN mrp_bom_line as boml
                                ON bom.id = boml.bom_id
                            INNER JOIN res_users as u
                                On so.create_uid = u.id

                            Left    Join (Select sp1.id, sp1.origin, sp1.state, spo1.qty_done, spo1.product_id, spo1.picking_id, sp1.date_done
                                            From stock_picking as sp1
                                            Full    Join stock_pack_operation as spo1
                                            On          sp1.id = spo1.picking_id) as del
                            On      so.name = del.origin
                            And     sol.product_id = del.product_id";

            if ($val != 2){
                $query = "
                            SELECT      Distinct ".$field." ".$query." Order By ".$group;
                            $_SESSION['being_used'] = "SELECT       Distinct ".$field." ".$query;
                            $_SESSION['field'] = $field;
                            echo 'set ok';
            } else {
                $query = "
                            SELECT      Distinct so.name ".$query." Order By so.name DESC";
                            echo 'set ok';
                            $_SESSION['being_used'] = "SELECT       Distinct so.name ".$query;
                            $_SESSION['field'] = $field;
                            echo 'set ok';
            }
        } else {
                echo $_SESSION['being_used'];
                echo $val;
                $search = $_GET['q'];
                $field_s = $_SESSION['field'];
                $query = $_SESSION['being_used']." Where".$field_s." Like '%".$search."%'";
        }
        $result = pg_query($query);
        while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly disregard looking at the queries since my only problem is the SESSION i don't know why it's getting destroyed evertime. TIA ppl!

Comment: Have you got `session_start();` anywhere? If it's not in any of the files you've included, e.g. connect.php, then it seems you're missing it. It won't work without it. Good practice is to place it before any output.

Comment: Your search is not even passing the string. Change the whole search thing to `$.get("_db/getvalue.php?q="+escape(str),function(data) {$("#output").html(data)})`

Comment: Hi entiendoNull. I have it in my connect.php. Okay brother i'll take your advice in making it a good practice :D Thanks!

Hi mplungjan. I am able to pass it. look at my getvalue() function it is working. But i'll do what you said even though i dont know how to. Thanks alot all!

Comment: Or you can teach me how to try why you are trying to say mplungjan :D thanks!

Comment: OMG @entiendoNull i tried to remove it from my connect.php and i tried to place it on top of the SESSION declaration and it worked! Thanks a lot man! You really saved my day! Here is a cookie for trying to help a dumb like me XD